# Magento subshops in subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I do have 5 shops:

http://www.mainshop.com
http://www.mainshop.com/subshop/
http://www.mainshop.com/subshops/
http://www.mainshop.com/subshops3/
http://www.mainshop.com/subshop4/

But everytime i click on the url for a categroy it keeps giving a Magento 404 error.

I did copy the index.php and htaccess to that subdirs and changed this line:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'subshop1';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
```

I also changed the configuration of that specific website:

[image: Configurationg]
The 404 comes to cms pages and category pages. Can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Try the solution of user2819389. Insert full links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento creates a full links like this:

```
{{unsecure_base_url}}../skin/
http://www.example.com/shop/../skin/
```

which wont work ofcourse... Try inserting the full links ;)

Like this:

http://www.example.com/skin/

Comment: I'm quite sure that will work. But the errors are from magento not the js and css files.

Comment: You'll get a 404 because the skin files are not found though.. So I would suggest you to try it out first.

Comment: Any solutions on the above?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used store views for each shop on one magento installation? You should not have sub directories for each shop and no need to copy index.php or any other file to a subdirectory. I think you have misunderstood how magento store views work. What you should do is enable the option for the storecode to be shown in each URL. When you setup your store view you specify the code which will be used (e.g. subdir1, subdir2 or whatever you want it to be). You need to use store views as you are using the same base URL which you need to change back to be default for each store view so it should be http://www.mainshop.com/ for every store view or website. This will allow you to achieve what you are trying to, without modding any magento code. Read this document in the wiki for more information how to do it properly http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/

[image]